# Add items to adapter in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I am developing an app in Xamarin.Android. Here, I am using listview with baseadapter to append the list of contacts. Now I need to append items once scrolled to end of the listview from database. I mean the concept is like "Load More Items". At first I add the items to adapter by re-creating it whenever scrolled to end of the listview. But I came to know that it is not optimal way from the link  [Load More Item in lazy adapter and listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065321/load-more-item-in-lazy-adapter-and-listview/50285834#50285834) . 
My code is as below,

allContactsList -> getting items from database

adapter -> My custom adapter

```
if (allContactsList != null && allContactsList.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        if(adapter == null)
                            adapter = new AllContactsListAdapter(this, allContactsList);
                        else
                        {
                           //Stucks here. I can't append to adapter
                        }

                        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                        listView.Adapter = adapter;
                    }
```

How can I append new items to an adapter in Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 3):

In your `Adapter` add a method, like this:

```
public void addItem(List<string> list)
{
    mList.AddRange(list);
    NotifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I have provided a demo on [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/ListViewAddItem).

Comment: Glad it helped, could you please accept it as answer?

Comment: One small doubt. Is it necessary to add method 'public void addItem(List<string> list)' in adapter?. Actually, I did adding items code in Activity itself. It also works.

Comment: I am the first one to answer your question. So have you turned to `Recyclerview`?

Comment: Using ListView or RecyclerView, depends on the need. Here, I used Listview because I need just to list the contacts. That's all. Refer this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957490/is-listview-completely-inferior-to-recyclerview?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

Listview is kind of deprecated and not be used anymore in professional apps. Use Recyclerview from support library instead. It's more optimal in loading items and has more features. The structure of loading items is almost the same. When you want to add items to an existing list, just add them to your content list and call `NotifyDataSetChanged();` after that, as @Joe Lv - MSFT said.

Answer (score 1):

My working code is as below.

```
List<MyClass> existingAllContactsList;
MyAdapter adapter;
ListView listView;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
...
...
BindData();
}

    void BindData()
    {

    var allContactList = list of items // from database

    if (allContactList != null && allContactList .Count() > 0)
                        {
                            if (adapter == null)
                            {
                                existingAllContactsList= allContactList;
                                adapter = new MyAdapter(this, existingAllContactsList);
                                listView.Adapter = adapter;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (existingAllContactsList!= null && existingAllContactsList.Count() > 0)
                                    existingAllContactsList.AddRange(allContactList);
                                else
                                    existingAllContactsList= allContactList;
                            }

                            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

}
```